# Define a callback for command start

Tags: r

I am trying to automatically time execution of all top-level expressions.  [Task Handlers](http://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf) are almost what is needed, however they are called only after the command completes, rather than before.

An alternative approach would be to modify every top-level expression to be wrapped in `system.time`, however I am not aware of a method to do this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two years late, but try this solution to automatically time all commands:

```
proc <- function(...) {
    utime <- proc.time()[1]
    utime_diff <- utime-get0(".prev_time", envir=globalenv(), ifnotfound=0)
    options(prompt=paste0(utime_diff,"s> "))
    assign(".prev_time", utime, envir=globalenv())
    return(TRUE)
    }
ret <- addTaskCallback(proc)
```

The "user time" returned by proc.time doesn't increment when idle, so it'll only calculate the time spent running the command.

This gives you pretty close to accurate measure, down to a 10th of a second at least:

```
start_time <- proc.time()[1]

st_time <- system.time({for(x in 1:10000000) {
    log(x)
}})[1]

pt_time <- proc.time()[1] - start_time

print(paste("time using proc.time()", pt_time))
print(paste("time using syste.time()", st_time))
```

"time using proc.time() 1.908"

"time using syste.time() 1.884"

Comment: That sounds like a good workaround, thanks for answering, I never thought of using user time for this.

Answer (score 8):

For completeness here is a function you can use as a task callback to automatically cause a system notification for any top level command that takes more than 5 seconds to run.

```
# devtools::install_github("gaborcsardi/notifier")
notify_long_running <- function(second_cutoff = 5) {
  last <- proc.time()[1]
  function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    duration <- proc.time()[1] - last
    if (duration > second_cutoff) {
      notifier::notify(msg = paste0(collapse = " ", deparse(expr)),
                       title = sprintf("Completed in %.02f (s)", duration))
    }
    last <<- proc.time()[1]
    TRUE
  }
}

addTaskCallback(notify_long_running())
```

Comment: Hey @Jim I'm not sure I am understanding what is meant by "top level command"...I installed notifier and then pasted and ran the above code..running `Sys.sleep(8)` should cause a notification afterward correct?

Comment: No, this uses user time, not elapsed time and sleeping does not change user time. See `?proc.time` for more information. We need to use user time because the elapsed time will include idle time just sitting at the command prompt. To test it is working you need to actually do something, e.g. `for (i in 1:100000000) i + 1`

Answer (score -2):

There's no real way to profile "top-level commands" because R doesn't know what those are. How are you defining them?

If system.time is not granular enough for you (because it doesn't look at individual pieces of code), my suggestion would be to go in the opposite direction and use [Rprof](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/Rprof.html), which allows you to start and stop the timing of expressions and, on output (`summaryRprof()`) prints a breakdown by function call. Mind you, this is by function call, *not* by "top-level function" call: if you're looking specifically for R to benchmark whatever you think of as a top-level function, `system.time` may indeed be your best bet

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear.  I don't have a problem with the timing of system.time, however I cannot use it in a post-execution callback because the command has already executed.  I need a pre-execution callback as well.  Also top-level expressions are simply expressions without a parent expression and Task Callbacks are only executed after them, which is why I mentioned them in the question.

Comment: Aha! Misunderstood - my apologies.